# Is my reasoning correct to prove normal convergence of $\sum_{k}^{\infty}\ \frac{1}{n}(\frac{1}{2}\sin(x))^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

So I have to prove/test every type of convergence (point wise, uniform, absolute, normal) of the following: $\sum_{k}^{\infty}\ \frac{1}{n}(\frac{1}{2}\sin(x))^{n}$

So I decided to start it of by testing normal, because if it does, then all the others are true by consequence.

If I understood the definition of normal convergence correctly, it is similar to absolute convergence but we don't fix the $x$.

I started: $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$: $\left |(\frac{1}{n}(\frac{1}{2}\sin(x))^{n})\right | \leq (\frac{1}{2n})^{^{n}}\leq (\frac{1}{2})^{n}$

And $\sum_{k}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{2})^{n}$ converges to 2, so $\left |(\frac{1}{n}(\frac{1}{2}\sin(x))^{n})\right|$ does converge, for every $x$. So I have proven normal convergence haven't I?

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: Pendantic side point: there are plenty of other types of convergence that these four, for example, convergence-in-measure.